# use cases of googleMaps distanceMatrix api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

just wonder what are the most common use cases for this API ?  we don't see them on common routing applications (google maps driving directions for example)

google pushed out this, and it's very heavy, so there's got to be some important use cases

Thanks
Yang

Comment: I mean apparently u could use the distanceMatrix api simply to get the distance between just 2 points. but it's better to use the directions api for that. for the N*M matrix case, it's hard to see some use cases.

Comment: Imagine a shop-finder, you have the location of the user and 25 shops. By using the distanceMatrix-API you would need 1 request to get the nearest shop. With the directions-API you would need 25 requests.

Comment: thanks, this explains the 1*N case, but what about the M*N cases ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the M x N case: 
You have a delivery merchandise (pizza joint) with *M* not-currently-occupied vehicles in a predefined area, and *N* different target locations to serve at a given slice of time.

In order to find the optimal route to N locations for your vehicles, you could run a distance matrix query and match the closest driver to the appropriate itinerary.

Second example: As a regional bank operations manager, you would want to keep your ATM information up-to-date, so you batch update their global positions (M x M) and the closest X ATMs to each every night once, or on each individual position update (1 x M).

Comment: thanks Bora.  I can see the use case of the vehicle routing application. I just feel that those use cases (such as UPS, Fedex) are very specialized and few, what's more, those companies place so much emphasis on routing that they develop their huge in-house research teams to do this, so it's hard to see that they would use google api for this.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't believe how much smaller banks would use google maps data for said purposes. And btw, how about a +1? :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be used in various ways but a very good application can be the analysis/evaluation of traffic systems. You might get the distances and times between various points at different points in time. This can help in reducing congestion in urban areas.